# Ordered or unordered Sequence problem in java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, break

I am facing problem in solving the question below:-
(can someone please help????)

**Write a program that reads a sequence of integer numbers and outputs true if the sequence is ordered (in ascending or descending order), otherwise, false. Keep in mind, if a number has the same value as the following number, it does not break the order.
The sequence ends with 0. Do not consider this number as a part of the sequence. The sequence always has at least one number (excluding 0).**

code which I wrote(For this code I am getting runtime error).....

````
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int number2;
        int number3;
        int number4;
        int prev;
        int mid;
        int next;
        int flag = 1;
        boolean val = true;
        while (val) {
            if (number1 > 0) {
                 number2 = scanner.nextInt();
                if (number2 > 0) {
                     number3 = scanner.nextInt();
                    if(number3 > 0){
                        prev = number1;
                         mid = number2;
                         next = number3;
                        if (prev >= mid && mid >= next || prev <= mid && mid <= next) {
                            number4 = scanner.nextInt();
                            prev = number2;
                            mid = number3;
                            next = number4;
                            flag = 1;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (number1 >= number2 && number2 >= number3 || number1 <= number2 && number2 <= number3) {
                            flag = 1;
                        } else {
                            flag = 0;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (number1 >= number2 || number1 <= number2) {
                        flag = 1;
                    } else {
                        flag = 0;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                flag = 0;
            }

        }
        if (flag == 1) {
            System.out.println(true);
        } else {
            System.out.println(false);
        }

    }
}```
````

Comment: Just a side comment... Since the number of inputs will vary, you should use a while loop to accept the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was a little bit messy, I will post a cleaned up version and explain the single steps.

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //firstable, you do not need to declare seperate variables for the number 
    //you want to enter, but you can use those (here currentNumber is the 
    //number typed in most recently, midNumber is the number before that, 
    //previousNumber is the one before that); they are initialized with 0 for 
    //reasons you will they later
    int currentNumber = 0, midNumber = 0, previousNumber = 0;
    boolean flag = false;

    //a while loop, which asks for new numbers, as long as the user does not 
    //break it
    while(true){
        //the user enters a number, which is the new current number
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        currentNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        //if the entered number is 0 and there was one number entered before,
        //the while loop breaks and the process ends
        if(currentNumber == 0 && midNumber != 0){
            break;
        }
        //there have to be at least three numbers in the sequence for it to be 
        //tested, otherwise the sequence is always true, so there have to be a 
        //midNumber and a previousNumber
        if(previousNumber != 0 && midNumber != 0){
            flag = false;
            //the flag is only true, if the three entered numbers are either 
            //descending or ascending
            if(
                (previousNumber <= midNumber && midNumber <= currentNumber)
                ||
                (previousNumber >= midNumber && midNumber >= currentNumber)
            ){
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        //the previous number is set to the midNumber, the midNumber is set to 
        //the currentNumber
        previousNumber = midNumber;
        midNumber = currentNumber;
       //since the process has not been terminated by the user, the while-loop 
       //starts over
    }
    // for memory reasons, the scanner has to be closed, since it will not be 
    //used after the while-loop, it will be closed here
    scanner.close();

    //the flag is printed; true if the sequence is true, false if otherwise
    System.out.println(flag);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Here is one another solution:--(finally optimized it).

````
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int oldNum = scanner.nextInt();
    int newNum;
    int asc = 0;
    int dec = 0;
    while ((newNum = scanner.nextInt()) != 0) {
        if (newNum > oldNum) {
            asc++;
        }
        if (newNum < oldNum) {
            dec++;
        }
        oldNum = newNum;
    } 
    System.out.println(asc == 0 || dec == 0);
}
}```
````

Comment: What approach did you use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int countOfNumbers = -2, ascPairs = 0, descPairs = 0;
        boolean isOrder = false;

        int temp = scanner.nextInt();
        countOfNumbers++;
        int first = temp;

        while (true) {
            temp = scanner.nextInt();
            countOfNumbers++;
            if (temp == first) {
                ascPairs++;
                descPairs++;
            }
            else if (temp > first && temp != 0) {
                first = temp;
                ascPairs++;
                isOrder = true;
            }
            else if (temp != 0){
                first = temp;
                descPairs++;
                isOrder = true;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();

        System.out.println((countOfNumbers == ascPairs && isOrder)
                || (countOfNumbers == descPairs && isOrder)
                || (countOfNumbers == 0)); 
                // last string is needed if validator considers 
                // one number like an ordered sequence
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you maybe add some explanation on what you solve and how, here?

Answer (score 0):

Just made small changes from the already given solution.

This Solution is Optimal for the following input case:

100 101 102 103 104 105 106 105 104 0

Ans: False. (As it is Neither in Ascending or descending order).

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int current = 0, mid = 0, previous = 0;
        /* Initialized three variables. current denotes current entered element.
        mid denoted element before current element. previous denotes element before mid element.*/

        boolean flag = true;
        /* "input case : 1000 0 " , the given input case
        must return true as it is in order.*/

        while(true){  //while loop to take user input until and unless a specified condition is satisfied.
            current = sc.nextInt(); // to get input from user and set as current value.

            if(current == 0 && mid != 0){

                break;
            }
            /*  if there is a certain condition where current element is zero and
            previous element is having non-zero element. then we break the loop.*/
            if(previous != 0 && mid != 0 ) {

                if( (previous <= mid && mid <= current) || (previous >= mid && mid >= current) ) {
                    flag = true;

                } else {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            /* ->in above two if conditions are used in first IF we check whether previous and
            mid element are having non-zero element. in second IF condition we check that whether these three consecutive
            element are in ascending or descending order.
            ->if any one of the condition is true we set flag as "true".
            ->In else section we set flag as "false" and break the loop when the three consecutive sequence are not in
            ascending or descending order. */

            previous = mid;
            mid = current;

            /* finally , we assign the mid element to previous and current element to mid , so to keep
            updating the sequence of consecutive number.*/

        } //while loop is closed.
        sc.close(); //closing the Scanner.
        System.out.println(flag); //State of the flag is printed.
    }
}
```